# Bash color shell on Mac?

Tags: macos, bash, shell

How can you make a bash shell list executable files in a different color than non-executable files?

I've tried editing `~/.bashrc` to contain the following line (it's otherwise empty):

```
 LS_OPTIONS='--color=auto'
```

But it's not working. What am I doing wrong? I'm working on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 8):

To turn on colour output from the `ls` command without having to create an alias to `ls` or download any additional software, add the following to your `~/.bash_profile`:

```
# Terminal colours
export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=ExFxCxDxBxegedabagacad
```

If you don't like those colours you can use [this ls color generator](http://geoff.greer.fm/lscolors/) to customize that color list to your liking.

You'll need to do:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

After making any changes for them to take effect in your existing shell.

Comment: no, it doesn't help at all

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that OS X doesn't have GNU `ls`; while its `ls` does support file name coloring, it can only do so by the type of file (file, directory, symlink, device special file, fifo, socket...).  Install `coreutils` from Fink/MacPorts/HomeBrew, then use `alias ls='gls --color=auto'`.

Comment: Thanks. I've installed `coreutils` from MacPorts. Should the `alias` line be in `~/.bashrc`? That's where I've put it, but I'm not seeing any difference.

Comment: `~/.bash_aliases` may work better.  I also found that I needed to run `eval $(gdircolors -s)` to set it up.

Comment: @AP257: On my Mac, I put aliases into the .bash_profile

Comment: @Hai Vu: That only works if you never use subshells.

Comment: @geekosaur `gdircolors: invalid option -- 's'` do you mean `--sh` ?

Answer (score 6):

BSD ls works [a bit differently](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ls.1.html)

```
alias ls='ls -G'
```

should work.

And this isn't bash coloring, it is `ls` doing the colorization.  When bash does a file list (try `echo *` in a directory) there is no way to colorize. Typing `ls -G` would work in any shell, though a shell (like bash) that has aliases makes it easier.

Answer (score 6):

On the Mac, you need to use

```
export CLICOLOR=1
```

I put that in the .bash_profile. However, I prefer Rich Homolka's solution to alias ls with -G flag. If you want to customize the colors:

```
man ls
```

and search for LSCOLORS

Answer (score 1):

Consider installing `brew` and using the GNU version of ls and other tools.

Install XCode from the AppStore.

Install [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/)...

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Install coreutils...

```
brew install coreutils
```

Add to the bottom of your `.profile`...

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"
export MANPATH="/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnuman:$MANPATH"
```

I alias `ls` in my `.profile` to do colors for everything and a shortcut for full list.

```
alias ls='ls --color'
alias l='ls -lah'
# -l     use a long listing format
# -a     do not ignore entries starting with .
# -h     with -l and/or -s, print human readable sizes (e.g., 1K 234M 2G)
```

There are a bunch of `LS_COLORS` options on [github](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=LS_COLORS).

Answer (score -1):

`bash` is only a shell, it does not list files. It executes commands, such as `ls`.

The `--color` option (and long options in general) is specific to the version of `ls` from GNU *coreutils*, which comes with most Linux distributions. On the other hand, Mac OS X has BSD roots and uses the BSD version of `ls` which does not support colouring.

Comment: -1: It *does* support colouring, just with a different command-line flag: `-G`.